# Why does my website have a gap on the iphone and ipad when portrait?! driving me crazy

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, ipad

I'm on the verge of eating my computer, bascially i'm a first year student doing HTML and CSS, just started with media queries while i've been off and am extreamly proud of my website, but when I view on the portrait mobile or ipad it loads very nicely and does exactly what I want, but you can slide slightly to the right for some reason and I don't know how to fix it! I have a small gap that I can't get rid of, why is this happening? my website is here [www.webmonsters.co.uk](http://www.webmonsters.co.uk) i'm very new to this.

Thank you.
UPDATE:
So I just worked out what it was, when I scaled down the slowly in brackets with the

highlighted I noticed that the

elements was no scaling with the browser windown, But when I put a 90% it worked and got rid of the gap! thanks for all your help guys.

Comment: A good first step would be to try to narrow the problem down a bit. Try eliminating any part of your website that does not cause the problem, until you are left with a (hopefully) short bit of HTML and CSS. Post that here, and someone will probably be able to help.

Comment: You were right seamus, thanks, I found the problem eventually breaking it down bit by bit.